# Can I retrieve documents of same subcollection in different collections with the same name, using Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Android app and I use Firestore to store my data. I have a collection of **Users**, and every user has a subcollection called **Posts**. Is there any way to retrieve all posts from all users to show them on my apps feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to retrieve all posts from all users to show them on my apps feed?

Sure, it is. You need to use [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

> Use a collection group query to retrieve documents from a collection group instead of from a single collection. In code should look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
rootRef.collectionGroup("Posts").get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

Using the above code, you'll be able to get all `Post` objects that exist within all subcollections named `Posts`.

Comment: Sorry mate, just tried. It worked just fine, god bless you! Cu alte cuvinte multumesc, Alex! Si multumesc si de cererea de checkmark. Nu stiam de el, credeam ca se da doar upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to get all the documents from all subcollections with the same name.  For example:

```
db.collectionGroup("Posts").get()
```